# How SSH forward HTTP request to backend server?

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

We have three machine, say, A, may laptop, B, the jump machine, and C the web server. The jump server can access from public network without any limitations, but web server C is limited, and *only* port 22 (SSH service) is opened for B, and they can talk dual-direction only via SSH.

We want to deploy a web server on C, say bind to port 7788, Can we configure B to forward the following request from A to C on port 7788, and without any configure to C?

```
curl B.ip:7788
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require any special configuration on B, except that port forwarding must be allowed (AllowTcpForwarding).

On A,

```
$ ssh -L17788:C.ip:7788 B.ip
```

Then on A, browse to

```
http://localhost:17788/
```

There's nothing special about 17788, you can use any free localhost port on A. I like to add 10000 to the tunnelled destination port to keep it simple and easy remember.